# How can I use a Broadcast Reciever and BOOT_COMPLETED to send a large list of notifications for a signed-in user

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, notifications, broadcastreceiver

In my Xamarin Forms application, I have a reminder feature built in that uses the cross platform plugin [LocalNotificationsPlugin.](https://github.com/edsnider/localnotificationsplugin) On the Github page, the author states for Android that:

> Currently, if the phone is re-booted then the pending notifications are not sent, you should save them out to settings and re-send on re-boot.

I have looked into how to doing this and it looks like I will need a broadcast reciever, triggered with a startup RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED in my manifest file. This works well when I test, calling the show notification code when I reboot my device. However, it gets a little more complicated when I try implementing what I need.

I have to dependency inject my setting service to retrieve the currently active user. I then have to use an injected todo service to get all of their reminders. Both of these are normally done as tasks when the app is running. But to do this from a broadcast reciever, it appears I either need to uses `GoAsync()` (for operations lasting no more than 10 seconds), or start an `IntentService`. I'm not sure which of these would be more suited, but my guess is an IntentService as the user might have a lot of stored reminders.

I'm also trying to work out if our Security API will be able to return the currently logged in user if the app is not running.

Debugging is also a headache with this. Most guides online tell you how to reattach to a process when Android Studio or Eclipse is involved, but Visual Studio and Xamarin don't seem to have any way to do this.

1. So I suppose my main questions are: Am I right in using a Broadcast Receiver and possibly an intentservice?
2. Can a stored user be accessed even if the app is not running?
3. Are there ways to effectively debug when using Broadcast receivers after rebooting? I've tried reattaching the debugger and logging to the DDMS but haven't had much success in seeing what's going on.

A sample project trying to do exactly what I'm doing would be very helpful to me, but I'm struggling to find one that's comparable to my problem.